# AppleScript returns the last Finder's name when I ask for the front window's name

Tags: applescript, finder

I started experimenting with AppleScript just recently, following an online tutorial. Right at the beginning it is not behaving like it is predicted.
I open up two Finder windows, and give the following command:

```
 tell application "Finder" to get the name of the front window
```

Then it tells me the second Finder windows name, while it is not up front, and happens to be my home folder. Then I open 3 Finder windows, and the script answers me by telling, that the front window's name is the name of the one behind all the others. (the first window I opened)
 Is it maybe about some settings in the AppleScript applications's preferences? Thanks in advance! Greg

Answer (score 0):

I have found some sort of solution. I had multiple Desktops opened on my Mac, and I was running AppleScript on a separate Desktop in fullscreen mode, and the Finder windows were opened on an other Desktop.
When running the script on the same Desktop, everything works fine.